# Angular: JWT token does not get saved in local storage first time

Tags: angular, authentication, jwt, local-storage, token

In the code below you can see that I try to save a firebase token in local storage after login, which also works fine. 
The problem is that navigation runs before the token is set in local storage, and the user therefore has to press the login button twice.

Why this is happening? how can I fix it? This is the relevant code:

```js
public signIn(email: string, password: string): Promise<User>  {
    console.log('Signing in as: ', email);

    this.userData = this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then( credential => credential.user );

    this.setToken();
    if (!this.isAuthenticated()) {
        console.log('not authenticated');
        this.router.navigate(['']);
      }
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    return this.userData;
  }
  
   setToken() {
    // this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true).then((token) => localStorage.setItem('tokenId', token));
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
           firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then((token) => localStorage.setItem('tokenId', token));
           console.log('set token succes');
      } else {
          console.log('set token failed');
      }
  });
  } 
  
  
     getToken() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
          firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then((token) => localStorage.getItem('tokenId'));
          // return this.currentTokenInlocal;
          console.log('get token succes');
        } else {
          console.log('get token failed');
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: I'm also not sure why this happens, would love to hear a proper explanation, but to fix this, I think you can move the navigation logic into the setToken() function instead. If I had to guess why it happens I would guess something about async.